# How can I create an overlay box using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I know that I can create a jQuery mobile overlay which loads content from another page.

Can I create an overlay manually to display a message to the user? Something sexier than the standard JS alert box?

**Update**

Instead of saying

```
<a href="my_message.html" data-rel="dialog">Show Message</a>
```

I want to say something like:

```
$.showDialog("Hello world!");
```

Comment: Have you looked at Dialogs? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

Comment: Dialog content must be stored on another page though right? I'd like to load this using JS from dynamically created content in the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To point you in the right direction:

Related:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UrdE6/11/
- http://jsfiddle.net/UrdE6/12/ (with function)
- http://jsfiddle.net/UrdE6/32/ (with page navigation)

JS:

```
var originalMessage = $('#the-content').html();
var dynamicMessage  = '<span>This is a dynamic message</span>'; // add dynamic content here

$('#dynamic').click(function() {
    $('#generic-dialog').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui) {
        $('#the-content').html(dynamicMessage).trigger('create');
    }); 
});

$('#original').click(function() {
    $('#generic-dialog').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui) {
        $('#the-content').html(originalMessage).trigger('create');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f" id="tasks">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Dynamic Dialog</li>
            <li><a href="#generic-dialog" data-rel="dialog" id="original">Show Original Dialog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#generic-dialog" data-rel="dialog" id="dynamic">Show Dynamic Dialog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is a page used for a dialog -->
<div data-role="page" id="generic-dialog">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="the-content">
        <h1>Delete page?</h1>
        <p>This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute.</p>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is almost perfect.

I still can't work out how to call a dialogue on page load though?

Comment: No. And for some reason when I mock the "click" event on "#dynamic" the close button won't work

Comment: I would need to see code to further debug. I did add a dynamic button in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UrdE6/35/

Comment: Phill, your solution works really well but it's not solving the issue I have. I wanted to open a dialog on page-load if certain criteria are met, not show the dialog on button click. I've been able to hack around this just now by adding a hidden link to the dialog and triggering $("#hidden_link").trigger("click")

Comment: maybe this should be another post/question with the code you are trying?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst this is almost a year late but is still as yet unanswered according to the OP's comments I thought I'd add my 2 cents.
With jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 at least you can achieve this from the same page.

Here is a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/z775f/3/

All that was added was to add this as the HTML

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="pageLoadDialog" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                Here is some demo text.
            </div>
</div>
```

Important to note that this sits outside of any other  tags as though the dialog were a "page" of its own.

Then I added a JS function to simulate conditional logic to display or edit the contents of the dialog.

```
function onPageLoad(showDialog) {
    if(showDialog){
            $('#pageLoadDialog').dialog();
            $.mobile.changePage('#pageLoadDialog', { transition: "none"} );
    }
}
```

Finally a call to that function with a boolean value to show the dialog on "pageload" which in a real environment could be added to the body or document's onload event.

```
onPageLoad(true);
```

All other code was forked from Phill Pafford's fiddle except updating the jQuery Mobile JS and CSS references to the new 1.2.0 RC 1 version.

Hopefully this can helps someone as it's not immediately clear how to do this from the same page as the jQuery Mobile examples on the topic reference an external .html

Answer (score 1):

You could use jtsage's [simple dialog plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/). It has support for a simple "OK, cancel" mode, a user input mode and a "blank" mode which allows you to specify whatever html you'd like.